# Invalid argument for class used 'XCUIElementTypeapp'

Tags: ios, ruby, selenium, appium

I am getting the below error message

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: An element could not be 
located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

I am using appium in conjunction with ruby and cucumber. Within appium I am getting the below error.

```
[JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST 
http://localhost:8100/session/A17F852A-3E7A-40D1-9626-
9E9BC666F16A/element] with body: {"using":"class 
name","value":"XCUIElementTypeapp"}
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":"Invalid argument 
for class used 'XCUIElementTypeapp'. Did you mean 
XCUIElementTypeXCUIElementTypeapp?","sessionId":"A17F852A-3E7A-40D1-
9626-9E9BC666F16A","status":15}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/a7ea0c9d-5aab-4780-a24c-
15e20c8aa5d8/element 500 44 ms - 164
```

I currently using XUITest for Xcode. I have searched online but not able to find out why the javascript cannot be located when the ios emulator has started.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: I have managed to find a solution to this issue. Thanks to anyone who tried to work on this.

Comment: If you have a solution why not post it as an answer for anyone else who has a similar problem?